# NoClassDefError: SnakeYAML, with Maven

Tags: java, maven, snakeyaml

I'm having a runtime issue occurring with SnakeYAML and maven. For some reason, I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with `Yaml` when I run my .jar.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml
    at my.package.TimberServer.loadConfiguration(TimberServer.java:56)
    at my.package.TimberServer.<init>(TimberServer.java:38)
    at my.package.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 3 more
```

Here is the section in my `pom.xml` in which I declare the dependency ([link to central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.4)):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't declare any repository for it.

Here is the code that calls (and imports) the Yaml class:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
// everything else is imported, yes

public class TimberServer {

    public void loadConfiguration() throws IOException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(); // Error occurs HERE.
        Map config = (Map) yaml.load(FileUtils.readFileToString(this.config));
        Map<String, String> serverConfig = (Map<String, String>) config.get("server");
    }
}
```

I get no errors when compiling with maven, which is the most confusing part to me - does Java not check for existent classes? I'm programming with an IDE (IntelliJ), which does not give any errors or warnings with the lines of code.

Comment: How are your packaging and running your application?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, packaging via `mvn package` and running via `java -jar target/*.jar ..args..`.

Comment: `mvn package` creates a JAR file only for the module itself. Its dependencies are _not_ included. If you want to _assemble_ a whole application, you must do more. Matt Raible mentioned the [Uber Jar Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). Another one is the [Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have it as a de

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thank you, I found the .jar but it was named with a suffix `-jar-with-dependencies`. The assembly plugin ended up working for me, but the Uber Jar plugin did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After help from @Seelenvirtuose in the comments, I came across this solution:

I was running `mvn package` alone - with no dependency plugin, which I learned is a necessity for packaging. However, in my specific case, the [Uber jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) did not want to work right and I had to use the [Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Note: the resultant .jar from the Assembly plugin will be named `target/yourProject-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. I overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including SnakeYaml in the JAR you're trying to run? If not, you'll need to 1) use Maven's uber-jar plugin to include it, 2) add the YAML JAR to your classpath when running the JAR or 3) use Maven's exec plugin to run your JAR so it can pick up the dependencies.

Comment: Maven Shade (uber-jar) gives the same error as before. I have the dependency in my `pom.xml` with default scope, which leaves it in the classpath forever by default.